# Using VlcManager with last version of Vlc.DotNet

Tags: c#, .net, dll, vlc, libvlc

I'm trying to use the Vlc.DotNet library for my WinForms C# application. I wan't to use the VlcManager from the Core.Interops of the Vlc.DotNet library but there is no recent documentation. In earlier version you can create an instance of the VlcControl and the VlcManager and set the VlcManager to the VlcControl, but this isn't availible anymore within the last version of Vlc.DotNet.

Can anybody tell my how I can add (multiple) VlcControls to a VlcManager? This should decrease memory usage and gives the possibility to use more functionalities, like NextFrame.

Code I could use in earlier versions:

```
Vlc.DotNet.Forms.VlcControl vlcControl = new Vlc.DotNet.Forms.VlcControl();
Vlc.DotNet.Core.Interops.VlcManager vlcManager = new Vlc.DotNet.Core.Interops.VlcManager();
vlcControl.Manager = vlcManager;
```

Answer (score 0):

Manager is now a property of VlcControl's "VlcMediaPlayer" property and does not need to be created separately any more

```
Vlc.DotNet.Core.Interops.VlcManager vlcManager = vlcControl.VlcMediaPlayer.Manager
```