# Vlc.DotNet NextFrame

Tags: c#, .net, vlc, libvlc

I'm using the `VlcControl` from the `Vlc.DotNet` library, but I can't figure out how to use the `NextFrame` function within the last version.

This command isn't available in the `VlcControl` class, only within the `Core.Interops.VlcManager` class, but I don't know how to call it from my `VlcControl`.

Comment: better format; deleted "forms" tag

Comment: Do you need help, in general, on how to invoke code from a different class or is it something specific? Please try to edit your question so that we can zero in on your problem

Comment: I've imported the NuGet package of Vlc.DotNet. Now I have a VlcControl within my toolbar, so I can drag & drop the control to my form. This seems to work, it's also possible to call functions from that control, like a Play/Pause function, even a Record function is availible. But I can't seem to figure out how to use the NextFrame function because this isn't implemented within the VlcControl itself. With the VlcControl you'll get the additional library Core.Interops.VlcManager, which contains this NextFrame function. But I can't seem to figure out how to call that function from the VlcControl.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30028851/using-vlcmanager-with-last-version-of-vlc-dotnet

Comment: @WesleyLalieu Having the same issue..Any workaround?

Answer (score 2):

You can move to next frame by increase the time like this

```
 vlcControl1.Time += 1000/FPS;
```

previous frame :

```
 vlcControl1.Time -= 1000/FPS;
```

**`FBS`** can be from

`ShellObject obj = ShellObject.FromParsingName(fileSource.getCurrentFile().FullName);
FPS = obj.Properties.System.Video.FrameRate.Value != null ? (int)(obj.Properties.System.Video.FrameRate.Value / 1000) : 22;`

**Note that :**

1. `ShellObject` from `NuGet` "WindowsAPICodePack-Shell"
2. I have assigned 22 because there is some file return null in `obj.Properties.System.Video.FrameRate.Value`
3. `fileSource.getCurrentFile()` this is a `FileInfo` Object that contains video file.

too late but maybe somebody find it helpful :)

Comment: As is mentioned in the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30028851/using-vlcmanager-with-last-version-of-vlc-dotnet provided by Wesley Lalieu, it's easier to use vlcControl1.VlcMediaPlayer.NextFrame()